# Unresolved externals error in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lnk2019, unresolved-external

i am learning vc++ and checking with code for usage information of memory. this program is giving me three errors of unresolved externals..

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetProcessMemoryInfo@12 referenced 
in function "void __cdecl PrintMemoryInfo(unsigned long)" 
(?PrintMemoryInfo@@YAXK@Z)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EnumProcesses@12 referenced in 
function _main

error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals.
```

Code::

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1

void PrintMemoryInfo( DWORD processID )
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

    // Print the process identifier.

    printf( "\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID );

    // Print information about the memory usage of the process.

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                    PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                    FALSE, processID );
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return;

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
    {
        printf( "\tPageFaultCount: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PageFaultCount );
        printf( "\tPeakWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X\n", pmc.WorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PagefileUsage ); 
        printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakPagefileUsage );
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main(void)
{
    // Get the list of process identifiers.

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the memory usage for each process

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        PrintMemoryInfo( aProcesses[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1` Did you do that?

Answer (score 8):

The header file that declares the function is used by the compiler to compile your code. The linker though does need a definition of the external functions that are used. That is typically supplied in an import library. The error message tells you that the linker has no such definition.

You have to include the respective library for `psapi.h` file.

```
#pragma comment( lib, "psapi.lib" )
```

EDIT::
From the [MSDN-Remarks Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to the
>   TARGETLIBS macro and compile the program with **-DPSAPI_VERSION=1**.

Extra::

`#pragma comment` is a compiler directive which indicates Visual C++ to leave a comment in the generated object file. The comment can then be read by the linker when it processes object files.

`#pragma comment(lib, libname)` tells the linker to add the 'libname' library to the list of library dependencies, as if you had added it in the project properties at `Linker->Input->Additional dependencies`

See [#pragma comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: That could be `kernel32.lib` too, depending on the OS version (according to MS documentation on [GetProcessMemoryInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this

```
#pragma comment(lib, “psapi.lib”)
```

Comment: That could be `kernel32.lib` too, depending on the OS version (according to MS documentation on [GetProcessMemoryInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).